# AWS SMS NOT Delivered Despite Success Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms

I have seen the posts on StackOverflow with similar issues as mine, but none of them helped me resolve the issue. This is why I am creating a new post.

When I first set AWS SNS up, I tested sending SMS using the online console, it worked!
Then I wrote PHP code to send a sample message. I got some errors but was able to resolve them easily. However, when I got a success response, the message was not received at all.

I thought it is a Limitation issue. So I contacted AWS and increased my limit to 20US/month. I updated the preferences, but still the same result. I get a success response, the dashboard shows that a message was sent successfully (although it takes time to update the number of messages sent). But the message is not received.

Here is my code for reference:

```
<?php
require './aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$sdk = new SnsClient([
  'region' => 'us-east-1',
  'version' => 'latest',
  'credentials' => [
    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  ]
]);

try {
  $result = $sdk->publish([
    'Message' => 'Reminder - You are scheduled for a session on 2020-05-20 at 4:30 PM',
    'MessageStructure' => 'String',
    'PhoneNumber' => '+1XXX789XXXX',
    'MessageAttributes' => [
      'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => 'MyName'
      ],
      'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => 'Transactional'
      ]
    ]
  ]);
  var_dump($result);
  echo "\n";
} catch (AwsException $e) {
  // output error message if fails
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

And here is the result object:

```
object(Aws\Result)#119 (2) {
  ["data":"Aws\Result":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["MessageId"]=>
    string(36) "8cf11950-cdb0-5503-9b69-4e6e9b61eaba"
    ["@metadata"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["statusCode"]=>
      int(200)
      ["effectiveUri"]=>
      string(35) "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
      ["headers"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["x-amzn-requestid"]=>
        string(36) "0488b803-8776-57bc-b9a9-ef3dd1a71805"
        ["content-type"]=>
        string(8) "text/xml"
        ["content-length"]=>
        string(3) "294"
        ["date"]=>
        string(29) "Tue, 19 May 2020 21:50:09 GMT"
      }
      ["transferStats"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["http"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["monitoringEvents":"Aws\Result":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I am out of ideas. Not sure how to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to send to multiple device / carrier and all of them fails?
SMS tech is known to be hit or miss

Comment: I forgot to mention that after I created the PHP code, sending through the online console now also doesn't work. It shows as 'sent' but nothing is received.

No I haven't attempted different carriers. I thought the carrier which had worked in the first Console test should still work fine from the PHP code.

Also, I am using Transactional SMS TYPE. Shouldn't this somehow guarantee receipt of my messages?

thank you

Comment: No. Transactional SMS does not guarantee delivery. I tested multiple time. By the way you described it, maybe your carrier blocked SMS from some AWS sender.

Comment: Not sure how to mark your answer as what has helped me in my case. I don' t know why but messages are not received on my phone, however, they are received by other phones.
This is strange! And not consistent! how would I know if a certain phone will/will not receive the message! strange. Thanks anyways @qkhanhpro

Comment: I put the answer in the answer box. Hope this will help others in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe by SMS's nature it can fail from time to time.

By my own observation, AWS employ some regional SMS providers that will help them send the SMS to your carriers.

Sometimes the SMS provider fails to send. Sometimes they are rejected by the receiving carrier.

At the moment, we have no way to be sure if It fails ( and react on this situation ) If the SMS is critical to your business, I suggest using another SMS service  in conjunction with AWS.